# Linq Query fail to execute method

Tags: c#, linq

While learning Linq, I wrote the code bellow, the problem is that "PrintResults()" method is never executed. I don't understand why!?
Is what I m trying to do possible?

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Linq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] scores = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            //IEnumerable<int> query =
            //    from score in scores
            //    where score % 2 == 0
            //    select score;
            // Console.WriteLine(score);

            IEnumerable<int> queryResults = scores.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList().Take(2);
            PrintResults(queryResults);
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> PrintResults(IEnumerable<int> input)
        {
            foreach (var score in input)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(score);
                yield return score;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...is ***never*** executed, or (from what I'm reading) reaches the `yield` and then stalls?

Comment: Side-note: in general i would not use `somequery.ToList().Take(2)` but `somequery.Take(2).ToList()`. The former creates and fills a list from a query and then creates a new query that takes 2 from this list. This query will always be executed whenever you use it(for example in a `foreach` or with `First()` or `ToArray`). Instead you normally want to create a collection from the final query, that's what the latter approach does(`ToList()` at the end). You can declare both as `IEnumerable<T>` because the list implements it.

Comment: `PrintResults` should not return the items that you pass as parameter. Otherwise it's intent is very unclear and the output is just a side-effect. It should be `void`.

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs.....

Answer (score 5):

When a method contains a `yield return` statement, it becomes an "iterator block". It will be evaluated lazily. This means that the code will not execute until some client enumerates over the `IEnumerable<int>` that is returned.

To see the results, invoke it like this:

```
var results = PrintResults(queryResults);
foreach (var result in results)
{
    // do something
}
```

Another way to "collapse" the iterator is just to call `.ToList()` on the return value. That will cause it to be enumerated just like a `foreach` loop does:

```
var results = PrintResults(queryResults).ToList();
```

Jon Skeet describes iterator blocks in more detail [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx).

Comment: If this answers the question to your satisfaction, feel free to mark it as accepted (by clicking the check mark) to close the loop. Thanks!